# Why doesn't my .Net custom error handling work all the time?

Tags: asp.net, security

I've got following in my web.config:

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="vb" debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error.html"/>
```

It works fine, displaying my custom error page, for a standard error (such as a crash/request of page that does not exist).  However, it fails on the following specific request and exposes debug info:

```
https://mywebsite/Page.aspx?error=<iframe>
```

How do I capture ALL cases, including these?

Error page returned is:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error 

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What error message are you getting ?

Comment: Argh.  Trying to paste it in, but it insists on chopping off the code samples and only displaying the useless description...

Comment: Confused as to why I'm seeing that error page, when it clearly says that setting the defaultRedirect will result in me seeing my own error page instead.  Especially since my custom error page works for *most* errors...

Comment: What error is it not catching? A 404? A 500?

Comment: Appears to be 500 that is not being caught.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BTW, **if you are using IIS 7**

Consider following things:

1.) `<httpErrors>`:

`<httpErrors>` configures error pages in IIS itself, outside the web application. This handles all requests, whether they’re in fact handled by ASP.NET or IIS natively.

Eg.:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <clear />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/Errors/500.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Errors/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

2.) Use **HttpResponse.TrySkipIisCustomErrors** Property to gets or sets a value that specifies whether IIS 7.0 custom errors are disabled.

The TrySkipIisCustomErrors property is used only when your application is hosted in IIS 7.0. When running in Classic mode in IIS 7.0 the TrySkipIisCustomErrors property default value is true. When running in Integrated mode, the TrySkipIisCustomErrors property default value is false.

Comment: Using IIS 7.5 and adding <httpErrors> works perfect for us.  Our redirect destination is HTML and not ASPX, so that works better than the second method.

Comment: The key for me that helped here was existingResponse="Replace". Without that, some of my custom errors were skipped (depending on what was returned from ASP.NET). Thanks.